# Missing input file for rule all [snakemake]

Tags: python, concatenation, snakemake

I've read some other questions with the same topic but I cannot solve it at all...

I'm trying to concatenate some files when I have got a second one if not, do nothing... table:

```
name              | path                                                                        | path2
554_MO_GEM12_r070 | data/171219_NB501241_0070_AHCHYNBGX5/fastq/554_MO_GEM12_r070_S5_R1_001.fastq.gz  |
693_SP_GEM12_r070 | data/171219_NB501241_0070_AHCHYNBGX5/fastq/693_SP_GEM12_r070_S21_R1_001.fastq.gz | data/200914_NB501241_0451_AHFNHMBGXG/fastq/693_MO_reseq70_r451_S1_R1_001.fastq.gz
866_MO_GEM12_r070 | data/171219_NB501241_0070_AHCHYNBGX5/fastq/866_MO_GEM12_r070_S10_R1_001.fastq.gz |
708_MO_GEM12_r070 | data/171219_NB501241_0070_AHCHYNBGX5/fastq/708_MO_GEM12_r070_S9_R1_001.fastq.gz  | data/180201_NB501241_0088_AHJ2GHBGX5/fastq/708_MO_GEM12_reseq070_r088_S5_R1_001.fastq.gz
```

This is the (simplified) `Snakefile`...

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import subprocess

### loading samples
SAMPLES = pd.read_csv("prueba_snakemake.csv")
SAMPLES.name = SAMPLES.name.astype(str)
SAMPLES = SAMPLES.set_index("name")

### including rules
include: "rules/testings.smk"

rule all:
    input:
        expand(["data/processed/{sample}.test"], sample=SAMPLES.index)
```

... and this is the `testings.smk`:

```
def concatenate_fastq(sample, sample_df):
    res_file = f"data/processed/{sample}_concatenated.fastq.gz"
    if not os.path.isfile(res_file):
        cmd = f"cat {[sample_df['path']][0]} {[sample_df['path2']][0]} > {res_file}"
        subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True)
    return [res_file]

def get_fastq_files(wildcards):
    sample_df = SAMPLES.loc[wildcards.sample]
    if pd.isna(sample_df["path2"]):
        reads = [sample_df["path"]]
    else:
        reads = concatenate_fastq(wildcards.sample, sample_df)
    print(reads)
    return reads

rule test_rule:
    input:
        reads = get_fastq_files
    output:
        "data/processed/{sample}.test"
    shell:
        "touch {output}"
```

But something is not working well,

1. when concatenation is not performed none file is generated (and it'd be expected to be some *touch* files),
2. new concatenated files are correctly stored in the folder but they are not detected (?) by the `rule all`:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
['data/RUNs/171219_NB501241_0070_AHCHYNBGX5/fastq/554_MO_GEM12_r070_S5_R1_001.fastq.gz']
['data/processed/693_SP_GEM12_r070_concatenated.fastq.gz']
MissingInputException in line 18 of snake_flow/workflows/rules/trimming.smk:
Missing input files for rule test_rule:
data/processed/693_SP_GEM12_r070_concatenated.fastq.gz
```

I think is not a wildcard problem nor different output's paths. Any idea what I'm missing, please? Thanks.

Comment: You are concatenating in the function that should be used just for returning the filenames of the files that shall exist before you run the pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how snakemake handles this situation, a possible explanation is snakemake detects input files before executing the input function (if I was wrong please correct)

A better way to do this is to create a new rule, i.e., `rule concatenate`. Let this rule generates the input for your `test_rule`. An example:

```
def find_input(wildcards):
    sample_df = SAMPLES.loc[wildcards.sample]
    files = [sample_df["path1"]] if pd.isnull(sample_df["path2"]) else [sample_df["path1"], sample_df["path2"]]
    return files

rule concatenate:
    input:
        find_input
    output:
        "data/processed/{sample}_concatenated.fastq.gz"
    shell:
        "cat {input} > {output}"

rule test_rule:
    input:
        "data/processed/{sample}_concatenated.fastq.gz"
    output:
        "data/processed/{sample}.test"
    shell:
        "touch {output}"
```

Comment: Hi @Jianyu. Yes indeed, the problem was exactly what you said: snakemake isn't detecting the input files... your code works nicely! However, with it I'm concatenating all files regardless of having one or two paths, is there any way to concatenate only those samples with two paths and to create a symbolic link to the other ones with only one path?

Comment: I can think of an option is to have a input function for `test_rule`, if there is no "path2" file, you simply return "path1" filename, else return a concatenated file (which will be the output of `concatenate` rule)